# Given $a > b+c$, $e>d+f$, and $i>g+h$, can the quantity $a(ei-hf) + b(-di+fg) - c(dh+eg)$ ever be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, contest-math, determinant

Given positive reals $a > b+c$, $e>d+f$, and $i>g+h$, can the quantity

$a(ei-hf) + b(-di+fg) - c(dh+eg)$ ever be zero?

Comment: Have you tried using the inequalities of $a,e,i?$

Comment: yeah; I tried to show it's either positive or negative... but didn't succeed

Comment: the terms in the parantheses suggest a determinant expansion.

Comment: I think your last term should be $+c(dh-eg)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c\\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right).$ This gives your expression. From the given condition, the matrix is [diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), so it's invertible, whence your expression is never zero.

Comment: what is diagonally dominant?

Comment: see the wikipedia page - the proof that any strictly diagonally dominant matrix is nonsingular is by the Gershgorin circle theorem, which is really nice and should be introduced in undergraduate curriculum but... oh well

Comment: Cool. By the way, the determinant I had in mind was $\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a & -b & -c\\ -d & e & -f \\ -g & -h & i \end{array}\right).$ But unfortunately I had a typo; its determinant should be 
$a(ei-hf) + b(-di-fg) - c(dh+eg)$

Answer (score 0):

lyj's answer is great and likely provides the motivation behind creation of the problem. However, there is no need to use such machinery. We can also approach it directly.

Suppose that the value is equal to zero. which means that the determinant of the matrix is 0. We know that there is a (non-zero) eigenvector with eigenvalue zero. Let the eigenvector be $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{pmatrix} $. WLOG, assume that $x$ has the largest absolute value. Then

$$ |ax + by + cz| \geq |ax| - |by+cz|  > 0$$

This contradicts the assumption that the eigenvector has eigenvalue 0.

Comment: Calvin: I'm not sure if $|ax+by+cz|>|(b+c)x+by+cz|$ always hold. If $by+cz>0$, $ax<0$, and $|by+cz|>|ax|$, then the inequality isn't true since $-ax=|ax|>|(b+c)x|=-(b+c)x$ and $|ax+by+cz|=by+cz+ax<by+cz+(b+c)x=|(b+c)x+by+cz|$

Comment: Oh wait, if $x$ has the largest absolute value, then $|ax|\ge|by+cz|$. This inequality is true after all.

Comment: @user70520 Indeed, your way is much cleaner and avoids issues with signage. I've updated my answer.